# Any need for DNS over HTTPS if there is a VPN running?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, openvpn

I am using OpenWrt 22.03.3 with OpenVPN. I was getting DNS leaks ([ipleak.net](https://ipleak.net) was showing my country DNS), but after setting custom DNS (CloudFlare) for WAN and WAN6 in OpenWRT, [ipleak.net](https://ipleak.net) shows CloudFlare DNS in the country of the VPN server. So for example, if I choose Netherlands server in OpenVPN, [ipleak.net](https://ipleak.net) shows Netherlands CloudFlare DNS servers instead of my own country servers (I live far away from Netherlands).

So I am assuming, even though the custom DNS in WAN is 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, the DNS requests are going through the VPN. And so, as far as privacy goes, is there any need to setup DNS over HTTPS using a package like https-dns-proxy? I ran out of storage in the router, so could not install that package. Is it necessary (assuming that I trust the VPN provider)?

Comment: Yes; You should use https dns proxy.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please elaborate a little bit why I should use it? Isn't the DNS traffic already being encrypted if it is going through the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in using DoH if you're already using a trusted and functioning VPN. All traffic will go through the VPN, including DNS queries. If you use DoH, your VPN provider still can see what IP you're visiting, and in most cases, unless the site [supports ECH](https://blog.cloudflare.com/handshake-encryption-endgame-an-ech-update/), will still see what domain you're visiting through SNI. So all that extra effort and you're merely adding a yet-another party to get your internet activity.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, since ipleak.net is not showing a DNS server in my own country and only shows DNS servers in the VPN country, it is safe to assume that the DNS queries are indeed going through the VPN, and there is no need for DoH, is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.